# IF statement in batch causing issues. Works when ran individually?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

At work I set up several computers a day for new users. I'm using a batch file that gives 3 options:
1. Add new user
2. Change PC name
3. Both
They all work great when ran from their own batch files, but when copy/pasting the code into IF statements, only IF statement '2' works. What am I doing wrong?
Setup asking to enter 1, 2, or 3.
Thanks in advance!!

```
set /p choose=Enter your selection here:
if %choose%==1 (
set /p user=Enter Username, then press Enter to create new user with default password:
net user "%user%" LSCpass14 /add
)

if %choose%==2 (
set /P pcname=Please enter this computer's LSC Asset Tag number, eg. 1295:
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d "LSC-%pcname%" /f
set /p reboot=You will need to restart your computer for these changes to be applied.   Would you like to restart now? [y/n] )
if %reboot%==y start shutdown -r -t 00
)

if %choose%==3 (
set /p user=Enter Username, then press Enter to create new user with default password:
net user "%user%" LSCpass14 /add
set /P pcname=Please enter this computer's LSC Asset Tag number, eg. 1295 :
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d "LSC-%pcname%" /f
set /p reboot=You will need to restart your computer for these changes to be applied.   Would you like to restart now? (y\n) 
if %reboot%==y start shutdown -r -t 00
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code with enclosing all strings in double quotes where needed because of special characters in string.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "choose=Enter your selection here: "
if "!choose!"=="1" (
   echo Enter user name, then press Enter to create new user with default password.
   set /p "user=User name: "
   %SystemRoot%\system32\net.exe user "!user!" LSCpass14 /add
) else if "!choose!"=="2" (
   set /P "pcname=Please enter this computer's LSC Asset Tag number, eg. 1295: "
   %SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d "LSC-!pcname!" /f
   echo You will need to restart your computer for these changes to be applied.
   set /p "reboot=Would you like to restart now? [y/n] "
   if /i "!reboot!"=="y" start %SystemRoot%\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 00
) else if "!choose!"=="3" (
   echo Enter user name, then press Enter to create new user with default password.
   set /p "user=User name: "
   %SystemRoot%\system32\net.exe user "!user!" LSCpass14 /add
   set /P "pcname=Please enter this computer's LSC Asset Tag number, eg. 1295 : "
   %SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d "LSC-!pcname!" /f
   echo You will need to restart your computer for these changes to be applied.
   set /p "reboot=Would you like to restart now? [y/n] "
   if /i "!reboot!"=="y" start %SystemRoot%\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 00
)
endlocal
```

On last page output in a command prompt window after entering `help cmd` or `cmd /?` a list of characters is displayed which requires a string to be enclosed in double quotes. The parentheses and the square brackets belong also to this group of special characters. The batch code demonstrates why `()` have a special meaning and therefore strings containing them literally require surrounding double quotes.

And it is necessary to use delayed expansion of the environment variables as explained in help output after entering `set /?` or `help set`.

Comment: When I choose option 1 I still get a message explaining the syntax of the NET USER command. Yet if I run alone, works great. :/

Comment: As I wrote first version of batch code I had inserted `echo` before the commands `net` and `reg` and did not look on the output of those lines. Of course it is necessary to use delayed expansion.

Comment: Ahhhh perfect, have never used delayed expansion! Thanks much!

Comment: Well I can't upvote cause yet cause I have no rep, but marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

When the cmd parser reads a line or a block of lines (the code inside the parenthesis), all variable reads are replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the code. If the execution of the code in the block changes the value of the variable, this value can not be seen from inside the same block, as the read operation on the variable does not exist, as it was replaced with the value in the variable.

This same behaviour is seen in lines where several commands are concatenated with `&`. The line is fully parsed and then executed. If the first commands change the value of a variable, the later commands can not use this changed value because the read operation replace.

To solve it, you need to enable delayed expansion, and, where needed, change the syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation needs to be delayed until the execution of the command.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
....
if "%choose%"=="1" (
    set "user="
    set /p "user=Enter Username, then press Enter to create new user with default password:"
    if defined user net user "!user!" LSCpass14 /add
)
....
```

The rest of the blocks have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't upvote yet since this is first post and I have no rep, sorry!