# DOS batch file not setting the value of count

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch job that runs every week to calculate money spent by employees in a week.

`WriteToDBIndex` is a C# program that checks other process like if finance have finished processing data (i.e. entered all employees spending data). If yes, `WriteToDBIndex`, writes a row in `emptablestat` table with `JobStatusName` & `status` if all data is entered.

I need to keep checking this until count for `FINANCE & empstatus=1` is one. I have timeout set for 3600 seconds.

```
@ECHO OFF
set ERRORLEVEL=0
REM start "" "C:\WriteToDBIndex.exe"
:gobackloop
set ct=0
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
Echo There has been an error. 
goto end
)
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
Echo inside errorlevel zero
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlcmd -E -S "MYDATA\MYDB" -h-1 -Q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[emptablestat] where JobStatusName like '%FINANCE%' and empstatus=1"`) do set ct=%%i 

if %ct% EQU 1 (
echo starting 1
start "" "C:\CalculateMoneySpent.exe"
timeout /t 60
) 
if %ct% EQU 0 (
timeout /t 3600
goto :gobackloop
)
)
:end
echo END
REM cd ..
```

The value of variable **ct** is somehow always zero even after I have the count of one in `emptablestat` table. I am not sure why.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

First, read what [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) wrote as answer on [IF statement in batch causing issues. Works when ran individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084920/3074564) as it explains why environment variable **ct** is always read with value 0 below `for` loop in the `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0` block.

Second, see the batch code below which I could not test at all, but hopefully works.

```
@echo off
rem Running WriteToDBIndex.exe in a parallel process.
start "Write to DB index" "C:\WriteToDBIndex.exe"
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo Error: Failed to start WriteToDBIndex.exe!
   goto end
)

:gobackloop
set ct=0
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlcmd -E -S "MYDATA\MYDB" -h-1 -Q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[emptablestat] where JobStatusName like '%FINANCE%' and empstatus=1"`) do set ct=%%i

if %ct% EQU 1 (
   rem Running CalculateMoneySpent in this process.
   "C:\CalculateMoneySpent.exe"
) else if %ct% EQU 0 (
   timeout.exe /t 3600
   goto gobackloop
)

:end
cd ..
```

I'm not sure why you use command `start` to run `WriteToDBIndex.exe` in a separate process which is running parallel to this batch process.

A reason could be that `WriteToDBIndex.exe` runs very long and you want to finish this batch process already before `WriteToDBIndex.exe` terminated.

Or `WriteToDBIndex.exe` is a Windows (GUI) application and this is the reason for using command `start` although I don't know why not using in this case additionally parameter `/wait` to halt execution of the batch file until `WriteToDBIndex.exe` terminated.

But I suppose you have used command `start` because simply not knowing the different execution behavior of calling a console application with or without `start`. Therefore I suppose further that `CalculateMoneySpent.exe` is a console application with short execution time and removed command `start`.

See my answer on [How to call a batch file in the parent folder of current batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044) where I explained the 4 possibilities to **start** or **call** another batch file / console / GUI application from within a batch file.

Comment: when I try to Echo %ct% after the for loop I get the value of ct as '(1' instead of '1'. what is that??

Comment: What is the output of `sqlcmd -E -S "MYDATA\MYDB" -h-1 -Q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[emptablestat] where JobStatusName like '%FINANCE%' and empstatus=1"`? Perhaps not just `0` or `1` as you expect.

Comment: it is one. For testing I just have one record in DB.

Comment: I do not see where `(` in value of **ct** should come from in my batch code. I suggest to change the first line to `@echo on`, open a command prompt window and run the batch file in this window. Now you can see what really happens and you should see why **ct** has not just `1` as value.